# Camera not detecting text in portrait mode while using react-native-firebase-mlkit?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, portrait

I am using [react-native-firebase-mlkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase-mlkit) in my app and this package is used to detect the text taken from camera or from the saved images in gallery. It is working fine when I click an image in landscape mode, but it is not able to read image when clicking in portrait mode. This problem is specific to Android. Does anybody have any solutions for this issue?

Does anybody have any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You must take a picture with **fixOrientation: true**

`camera.current.takePictureAsync({fixOrientation: true})`

another important thing is; text which is taken in the photo must be portrait